# Tmux messing with Vim highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, tmux

When I load up vim inside tmux there is a background color behind all text as so:

[image]

If I load it up not in tmux I get the following:

[image]

I want it to be like image 2, I can not understand why tmux is interfering?

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers of this kind. Have you done a simple search before asking a question? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line to your `tmux.conf` file

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Add the line below to you shells rc file in my case its my `.zshrc`

```
if [[ $TERM == xterm ]]; then TERM=xterm-256color; fi
```

Add the line below to your `.vimrc`

```
set t_Co=256
```

The above configuration works for me, but if this fails try to follow this link for another methor to fix [Fixing Vim's Background Color](http://sunaku.github.io/vim-256color-bce.html)

Comment: No luck, is there anything special I need to do to enable .tmux.conf in tmux?

Comment: I have modified the answer.  try again @OtisWright  let me know if it fails.

Comment: @OtisWright give me more details about your shell and os you are using to run tmux and vim.

Comment: Hey @byaruhaf I am using oh-my-zsh tmux and vim I am currently getting this error with those settings:
`/home/otis/.zshrc:4: parse error near `]]'`

Comment: Hey @OtisWright can you post your .zshrc on a  gist or any public paste site.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/CrashyBang/53163b5bc63379b6e22712d021e756a9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37791/discussion-between-byaruhaf-and-otis-wright).

Comment: On my end, aside from the changes above, need to add this in `.vimrc` also: `set term=xterm-256color`, so my `.tmux.conf` still has `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`. Setting them both as `xterm-256color` or `screen-256color` didn't work.

Comment: Same problem with tmux, oh-my-zsh and NeoVim, any solutions for NeoVim?