# Truecolor (termguicolors) causes display issues in Tmux

Tags: tmux, iterm2

As far as my setup is concerned, I'm running Tmux 2.2 (with true color support enabled) inside iTerm2 version 3 on a Mac. To clarify, there are [other](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7112/tmux-messing-with-vim-highlighting) [questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/238/tmux-is-changing-part-of-the-background-in-vim) already answered which address essentially the same problem I am experiencing, but none of the offered solutions (`ttyfast` or `set t_ut=`) fix the issue for me unless I turn `termguicolors` off.

Here's what I see when I run Vim in iTerm2 directly. Everything looks as I expect:

[image: Vim in iTerm2]

But I end up with strange background issues when I run inside Tmux:

[image]

Now the colors are pretty close, so it might be hard to see, but it's actually very jarring when I'm running full screen with split panes and lots of text.

To my eye it looks like the text background color is rendering correctly, and the background color for *blank lines* renders correctly, but for some reason the background color past the end of the text renders incorrectly. This is probably consistent with other similar questions I've seen.

Here's a picture showing what I mean. Blank lines also render the background color correctly:

[image]

As a final data point, I ran `set termcap` to dump the terminal settings and verified that everything matches between when I run Vim in iTerm vs when I run in Tmux.

Some additional details brought out from the comments below:

- The theme always works in Neovim (v0.1.4), whether I run in Tmux or in iTerm directly. This leads me to believe it is not an issue with the theme, or with Tmux.
- The terminal in Tmux is set to `screen-256-color`. Because of limitations in the way Vim handles `termguicolors`, this means I end up having to manually set `t_8f` and `t_8b` values.

If anyone has any suggestions on what I can try to fix this issue, I'm all ears.

Comment: When you're in tmux, what's the output of `echo $TERM` (and also, what does `:set term?` in Vim output)?

Comment: In order to get `termguicolors` to work at all inside Tmux without manually setting `t_8f` and `t_8b`, I added `set-option -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` to my `.tmux.conf`. So the short answer to your question is that both `echo $TERM` and `:set term?` return `xterm-256color`.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1098/70524, `TERM` inside `tmux` should be `screen*`, not `xterm*`.

Comment: I've changed to `screen-256color` and set `t_8f` and `t_8b`, but the result is the same.

Comment: Apprentice author, here. Please use [the issue tracker](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice/issues).

Comment: @romainl I can do that, but I don't want to waste your time, and I'm not at all convinced the color scheme is the issue given the fact that it displays as expected in iTerm outside of Tmux. Also, I neglected to mention that it displays correctly in nvim in _both_ iTerm and Tmux. Would you still like me to open the issue?

Comment: Well… that would give me an incentive to take a look at that new "truecolor" thing.

Comment: @romainl No problem. I will open an issue as soon as I get back to my machine this evening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in Vim itself. The problem is resolved as of Vim 7.4.1942.

Comment: Link to the bug report: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/804